# Error When Using A Data Source Without A Password In Jetty 9

Tags: java, jetty, hsqldb, embedded-jetty

I was able to make the following example project work on my system using HSQLDB and Jetty:

- http://www.programmingforfuture.com/2011/02/in-process-mode-of-hsqldb-in-web.html

I then wanted to convert the project to use JNDI to reference the data source.
First, I added the following resource-ref to my `web.xml`:

```
<resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/mydatasource</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

I then added the following data source to my `$JETTY_HOME/etc/jetty.xml` file:

```
<New id="mydatasource" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
    <Arg></Arg>
    <Arg>jdbc/mydatasource</Arg>
    <Arg>
        <New class="org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDataSource">
            <Set name="Url">file:mytestdb</Set>
            <Set name="User">SA</Set>
            <Set name="Password"></Set>
        </New>
    </Arg>
</New>
```

...and then I referenced the data source using the following code:

```
try {
    //con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:mydatabase","SA","");

    InitialContext context = new InitialContext();
    DataSource dataSource = (DataSource)context.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/mydatasource");
    con = dataSource.getConnection();

    con.createStatement().executeUpdate("create table contacts (name varchar(45),email varchar(45),phone varchar(45))");
} catch (NamingException ne) {
    ne.printStackTrace(System.out);
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace(System.out);
}
```

I then deployed the app as an exploded directory and tried to start the Jetty process. 
When I did, it crashed and I got the following error message:

```
# tom at toshi in ~/Downloads/jetty-distribution-9.0.4.v20130625 [19:41:34]
$ java -jar ./start.jar                                                                                    <<<
2013-07-07 19:41:39.335:WARN:oejx.XmlConfiguration:main: Config error at <Set name="Password"/> java.lang.refle
ct.InvocationTargetException in file:/home/tom/Downloads/jetty-distribution-9.0.4.v20130625/etc/jetty.xml
2013-07-07 19:41:39.349:WARN:oejx.XmlConfiguration:main: Config error at <New id="mydatasource" class="org.ecli
pse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource"><Arg/><Arg>jdbc/mydatasource</Arg><Arg>|            <New class="org.hsqldb.jdbc.J
DBCDataSource"><Set name="Url">file:mytestdb</Set><Set name="User">SA</Set><Set name="Password"/></New>|       
 </Arg></New> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException in file:/home/tom/Downloads/jetty-distribution-9.0.4.
v20130625/etc/jetty.xml
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:509)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:651)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:99)
        ...
```

Ok, it doesn't like the fact that the password field is empty. So then I tried making this
change in my `jetty.xml`:

```
    <!--<Set name="Password"></Set>--> <!-- Got rid of this -->
    <Set name="Password" />
```

I still got the same error. So I then deleted the "Password" property from my data source
and I was able to start Jetty! The bad news is that now I get this error when I try to do
anything that references the database:

```
2013-07-07 19:49:09.682:WARN:jndi:qtp14895676-19: 
java.lang.Exception: org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDataSource: invalid RefAddr: password
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDataSourceFactory.getObjectInstance(Unknown Source)
        at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:321)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:476)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.local.localContextRoot.lookup(localContextRoot.java:518)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.local.localContextRoot.lookup(localContextRoot.java:533)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:468)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:536)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:536)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:536)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:551)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.java.javaRootURLContext.lookup(javaRootURLContext.java:117)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
        at Register.init(Register.java:31)
        ...
```

That warning then was followed by a null pointer exception.

So now it appears that the HSQLDB driver is counting on the existence of the password
field in the data source.

So that's my catch-22: I'm not able to start Jetty with an empty password field in my
data source, but if I omit it, the driver doesn't work.

Does anyone know of a way to create a data source with an empty password in Jetty?

Finally, I'm aware that I could a) not use JNDI or b) give the SA user a password. However, 
my particular project requires that I use JNDI and not give the SA user a password.

Comment: You must set the password for the HSQLDB JDBCDataSource. In this case as "" (a zero-length string). It seems JNDI is simply not setting the password when it is empty.

Comment: Thanks a ton Fredt, this fixed my problem! I wish I could say that this comment solved the problem.

Comment: You're welcome. Please answer the question yourself with the solution and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, set the password as "" didn't work.

Creating a java.lang.String resolved my issue.

```
<Set name="password">
    <New class="java.lang.String" />
</Set>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the recommendation fredt!

I simply had to specify the empty password the following way in my jetty.xml file:

```
...
<Set name="Password">""</Set>
...
```

After that everything worked perfectly.